# Password Checker in java with do while

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I need to write a password checker which ensures that password correct.

Firstly I prompt the user enter the password

Secondly, I prompt the user to reenter the password

thirdly, I need to check that the passwords are identical

But this steps need to repeat 1 through 3 until password is correctly entered twice.

Here is my code. But i cant understand the logic of repeat 1 through 3

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab4Exercise1{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.print("Enter Your password");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double password = sc.nextDouble;
        double reentered = sc.nextDouble;

        do {

        }while (password==reentered);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, are you sure you want your passwords to be `Double`s? That is, numbers like `2.71828`? Secondly, consider putting the password entry inside your `do` loop. Third, change the `==` to `!=` (you want to loop as long as they are *not* equal).

Comment: It is suggested to use Console.readPassword() method istead of using System.in.

Comment: Generally you would use a for-loop when you need to repeat something a particular amount of times, and a do-while when you unconditionally need to do something once, then repeat as necessary. Do you need to keep asking for the password until they match or do you need the while loop to handle both password requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab4Exercise1{
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double password;
    double reentered;
    do {
        System.out.println("(Re)Enter Password:");
        password = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Confirm Password:");
        reentered = sc.nextDouble();
    } while (password != reentered);

    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for but it gives error :  " class Lab4Exercise1 is public, should be declared in a file named Lab4Exercise1.java
public class Lab4Exercise1{"

Comment: @EmrahSarıboz Welcome to Java World! ;-)

Comment: @EmrahSarıboz Then use that info which error message is giving you. Remember that top level public classes need to be placed in `.java` files with same name as public class, like `public class Foo{}` needs to be placed in `Foo.java` file. So either rename your class to match name of your file, or rename your file to match name of class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code which fulfills your requirement. There might be syntax errors as I didn't use the eclipse.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab4Exercise1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double password, reentered;
        do {
           System.out.println("Enter Your password");
           password = sc.nextDouble();
           double reentered = sc.nextDouble();
           if(!password.equals(reentered)) {
               System.out.println("Passwords do not match. Please retry");
           } else {
               break;
           }
        }while (True);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class PasswordChecker
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1;
    String s2;
    
    do{ System.out.println("Create a Password");
        s1=scr.next();
        System.out.println("Re-enter to confirm the Password");
        s2=scr.next();
        if(!s1.equals(s2))
        {
            System.out.println("Password did not match");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Registration Success");
        }
            
    } while(!s1.equals(s2));
}       
}
```